# GDB command file in XCode

Tags: xcode, gdb

I'd like to add a file to my project that has a list of gbd commands and load that into GDB within xcode at any breakpoint. Looking at GDB documentation I see the "source" commmand, but it is unknown within xcode's gdb. Has anyone had success doing this?

source -f commandfile.gdb

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The source command appears to work although no options are supported if you are really using gdb as the debugger. In the debug console make sure it says "(gdb)" as the prompt. The default debugger now is LLDB instead of GDB. You can change this under Product -> Edit Scheme… and select the "Info" tab at the top. The "Debugger" popup will present you with GDB or LLDB.

Comment: Oh geeze.... it is LLDB. Is there an equivalent for LLDB? I mean loading a series of commands from a file?

Comment: @HCHogan In LLDB use the command source command to load breakpoint commands from a file. Supply the path to the file containing the commands.